# Flutter grpc credentials using .pem file

Tags: flutter, dart, certificate, grpc

I have a Flutter app that needs to communicate to a server using a secure client channel over grpc.

To try to create the client channel, I am using:

```
 final _channel = ClientChannel(_hostAddress,
      port: _port,
      options:
          const ChannelOptions(credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
            certificates: ??? ???
          )));
```

For the `certificates` part, the only I have is a certificate in a **.pem** file.

The documentation on the puv.dev page [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/grpc/latest/grpc/ChannelCredentials-class.html) is totally useless since it just points out that the certificates parameter is a **List of int**

How do I go from a **.pem** file to a **List of int**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the answer from **@alex_z** might be correct for other cases, it looks like the proper way to do this (if the certificate file is somewhere is assets, like in my case) is to do the following:

```
final cert = await rootBundle.load('assets/certificate.pem');

final certAsList = cert.buffer
        .asUint8List(cert.offsetInBytes, cert.lengthInBytes)
        .map((uint8) => uint8.toInt())
        .toList();
```

Like this, it can be passed to the `ChannelCredentials` without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dart does not have a byte type, so byte array is List or Uint8List. I suppose if you open you .pem file and read contents of the file as bytes you will get your List of int

```
Future<Uint8List> readCert() async {
  final File f = File('cert.pem');
  final bytes = await f.readAsBytes();
  return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys are all wrong, the flutter grpc takes `**.crt` file than `**.pem`

```bash
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout grpc_call_service.key -x509 -days 365 -out grpc_call_service.crt
```

```dart
  Future<ClientChannel> get_a_temprary_channel() async {
    final grpc_call_service_key =
        await rootBundle.load('resources/keys/grpc_call_service.crt');

    return ClientChannel(
      GrpcConfig.host_ip_address,
      port: GrpcConfig.call_service_port_number,
      options: ChannelOptions(
          credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
              certificates: grpc_call_service_key.buffer.asUint8List(),
              authority: GrpcConfig.host_ip_address,
              onBadCertificate: (certificate, host) {
                return true;
                // return host ==
                //     '${GrpcConfig.host_ip_address}:${GrpcConfig.call_service_port_number}';
              })),
    );
  }
```

https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc-dart#dart-protoc-grpc-ssl-example